# Updating single object in array (Transformable) from core data Swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift5

I have an Entity called "Contacts" with an attribute called "contactList" with type "Transformable". I tried to save and deleting is working fine. but updating a value of the particular record is not working

**Here it is my code**

```
   func updateRecord(primaryKey:String, mobileNumber:String) {
            if let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate{
                let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
                let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Contacts")

                do{
                    let objects = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
                    if objects.count > 0{
                        for object in objects{
                            let match = object as! NSManagedObject
                            let list = match.value(forKey: "contactList") as? [String:Any]
                            if list != nil && !(list!.isEmpty) {
                                let key = list!["taskPrimaryKey"] as! String
                                if key == primaryKey{
                                  match.setValue(mobileNumber, forKeyPath: "Mobile")

                                    do {
                                        try context.save() // <- remember to put this :)
                                    } catch {
                                        // Do something... fatalerror
                                        print("fatalerror : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                                    }
                                    break
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                } catch {
                    print("could not retrive error : \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }

            }
    }
```

Comment: Isn't it `list` you should update and not `match`? Off topic but maybe it is time to create a new entity for this contact list.

Comment: within the contact list, I need to update a single contact record using a primary key like username or mobile values

Comment: Exactly but your are not, `match.setValue(mobileNumber, forKeyPath: "Mobile")`

Comment: can please add code snippet

Comment: Something like `list["Mobile"] = mobileNumber`

Answer (score 0):

I assume `mobileNumber` is a `number`??

```
match.setValue(NSNumber(mobileNumber), forKeyPath: "Mobile")
```